# mod_security - IP access Issue

Tags: apache, permissions, owasp, mod-security

I'm trying to access my website using it's IP address, earlier it was working fine. But after I installed and configured mod_security and mod_security OWASP, Apache is giving out 403 error.

> **Forbidden**
>   You don't have permission to access / on this server.

What should be done so that I can access the website using the IP from the browser ??

Comment: You can see modsecurity audit logs to see which rule are blocking your transcation

Answer (score 1):

The rule for blocking direct IP access is in the CRS file here:

```
base_rules/modsecurity_crs_21_protocol_anomalies.conf
```

You need to get the ID of the rule and disable it using `SecRuleRemoveById`